# Stream File Directly to s3 using NodeJS+Express, aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, amazon-s3

I want to upload some large files directly to s3 via the browser with NodeJS, it is unclear how to prepare this file for upload to s3. There might be a better module (like Knox) to handle this case but I am not sure. Any thoughts?

File Object

```
  file: { 
     webkitRelativePath: '',
     lastModifiedDate: '2013-06-22T02:43:54.000Z',
     name: '04-Bro Safari & UFO! - Animal.mp3',
     type: 'audio/mp3',
     size: 11082039 
  }
```

S3 putObject

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket_name/'+req.user._id+'/folder', Key: req.body['file']['name'], Body: ???};
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Streaming is now supported ([see docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property)), simply pass the stream as the `Body`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var someDataStream = fs.createReadStream('bigfile');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey' } });
s3.putObject({ Body: someDataStream, ... }, function(err, data) {
  // handle response
})
```

Comment: Does this not require the file to be stored on hard disk before being uploaded to S3? I assumed OP wanted to skip the step of saving to disk and upload directly to S3 ... then again, I am a complete novice when it comes to file uploading.

Comment: You can use any stream for the upload - it doesn't have to come from the disc.

Comment: this method is able to upload only smaller files. For better performance and control I am using `s3.upload()`

Comment: Note that if you are piping this from another stream, you will receive an unknown content length error. I recommend using `upload` which does not have this problem and does have other advantages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38442712/1277350

Answer (score 3):

The `s3.putObject()` method does not stream, and from what I see, the s3 module doesn't support streaming. However, with [Knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox), you can use `Client.putStream()`. Using the file object from your question, you can do something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var knox = require('knox');

var stream = fs.createReadStream('./file');
var client = knox.createClient({
  key: '<api-key-here>',
  secret: '<secret-here>',
  bucket: 'learnboost'
});

var headers = {
  'Content-Length': file.size,
  'Content-Type': file.type
};

client.putStream(stream, '/path.ext', headers, function(err, res) {
  // error or successful upload
});
```

Comment: thank you, I know my question was a bit vague as there are a lot of factors contributing - I had a feeling Knox would be what I need to use, thank you

Comment: So just to get it straight, this will work without uploading the file to the web server first? I want to avoid that entirely

Comment: This will stream the file to the server. The main difference between this and `putObject()` is that the file doesn't have to be entirely loaded into memory, therefore allowing you to upload extremely large files.

Comment: I guess i'm only confused about the var stream = fs.createReadStream('./file'); doesn't this need to point to a file on the server?

Comment: The read stream points to a local file. It is the file that you intend to stream to the server.

Comment: Yes so where would this file live, if I am attempting to upload directly from browser

Comment: To get a file to s3, you'd first need to upload it to the Node.js server, then the Node server would stream it to the s3 server. Since you tagged Express, the file would live wherever the `bodyParser()` middleware put it. You'd then have to check the `req.files` object to find where the client uploaded the file. Once you have the location, just create a read stream to that location, and stream it to s3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40482/discussion-between-whiteb0x-and-hexacyanide)

Comment: Hey hexacyanide can you email me when you get a chance iamwhitebox@gmail.com

Comment: Why it doesn't work for big files? I try it for file of size > 990 MB and it gives me the following error: { [Error: write ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'write' }

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use multer-s3 instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3.

This post has some details also: [Uploading images to S3 using NodeJS and Multer. How to upload whole file onFileUploadComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898267/uploading-images-to-s3-using-nodejs-and-multer-how-to-upload-whole-file-onfileu)

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't streaming. You need to see a call to `pipe` somewhere or at least code to pipe by hand by using `data` event handlers. You are probably using the express bodyParser middleware, which is NOT a streaming implementation. It stores the entire request body as a temporary file on the local filesystem.

I'm not going to provide specific suggestions because of the promising results I got from a web search for "node.js s3 stream". Spend 5 minutes reading, then post a snippet that is at least an attempt at streaming and we can help you get it right once you have something in the ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

The v3, the PutObjectCommand can not write file stream to S3. We need to use the `@aws-sdk/lib-storage` library for uploading buffers and streams.

Example:

```
const upload = async (fileStream) => {
    const uploadParams = {
        Bucket    : 'test-bucket',
        Key    : 'image1.png',
        Body: fileStream,
    }

    try {
        const parallelUpload = new Upload({
            client: s3Client,
            params: uploadParams,
        });

        console.log('Report progress..')
        parallelUpload.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
            console.log(progress);
        });

        await parallelUpload.done();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Ref - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#s3-multipart-upload