# Is there anyway to upload a file to s3 from public url without downloading it using node js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, bubble.io

I have one url from which anyone can download file that is public url. I want to upload that file to s3 from that url without downloading it to local storage.
I have one plugin in bubble.io from where user will upload file and that plugin will return url like below and i have to upload that file to my private s3 bucket which user has uploaded in bubble.io .

URL - http://s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1633354808992x298365941824238600/Archive%20%281%29.zip

Is anyone have idea how to do this ?

P.S-  Above url is generated by bubble.io plugin

Comment: You will need to clarify what you mean; as is, this question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Question details edited @deceze

Comment: "Upload a file on S3 to S3 from that URL" is still… confusing. Can this be rephrased as *"how to transfer a file from S3 bucket A to S3 bucket B"*…?

Comment: No it's not like from s3 bucket to s3 bucket. S3 to s3 url means a url that is generated by buuble.io plugin which is aws url but we can not perform operation on bubble.io s3 as it's their personal storage @deceze

Comment: For your clarity you have this given url and using given url you have to upload a file to your own s3 bucket

Comment: https://pastebin.com/G2Nb9cBC  is example of proxy on the source url. Returns a stream instance than can be supply to std. aws-sdk.putObject() as shown :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36402569/560435